# Proper location for proc edits

Tags: configuration, macbook, proc

My hardware/kernel combination expose a particular bug(ish) that means my laptop doesn't sleep when the lid is closed. The fix is easy - it's simply:

```
root# echo XHC1 >/proc/acpi/wakeup
```

My question is, where is the proper location to have this happen on each subsiquent boot?

Comment: In `/etc/rc.local`.